# What is the physical difference between torque vs torque about a line?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

Suppose you are given a line $L$ in space, then if you have a system of particles with forces acting on them the torque about a point on the line, you have to sum $ \sum r_i F_i$ over all particles. However say you wanted to compute the quantity 'torque about the line', then you'd find that this quantity is independent of which point you take. This makes intuitive sense (to me) because we are torque components along this line. It can be said that this torque measures rotation about that line. [(Refer here for proof)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364303/how-torque-about-every-point-on-axis-is-same)

However, what does the actual torque which we calculate after we choose an arbitrary point on the line represent? Does it mean rotation perpendicular to that line.... that is something I can't grasp?

I hope for a clear and simple explanation of this quantity and how changes in this quantity and how variations in it change the motion physically.

---

**Illustration of what I mean:**

A line in space can be written by the equation $ \vec{r} = \vec{a_o} + \lambda \vec{v}$, now the vector connecting the point $a_o$ (*)to line is $ \vec{b}$. Suppose the location of force is $ \vec{j}$ from origin, the vector connecting the force vector to the line is $\vec{j} - \vec{r}$. We can write torque around $a_o$ as:

$$ \vec{\tau}  = ( \vec{j} - \vec{r}) \times \vec{F}$$

Now, it's pretty easy to see that the torque is dependent on the point we take on line as follows:

$$ \vec{ \tau(\lambda)}  = ( \vec{j} - (a_o + \lambda \vec{v} ) )\times \vec{F}$$

---

**Notes:**

- All the above discussion is in cartesian coordinates with an arbitrary origin which is not on the line.
- (*): Here I have switched between the representation of point using position vector and point $ \vec{a_o}$ is the position vector to the point $a_o$ with some coordinates.
- $ \vec{v}$ is a vector parallel to the line
- $ \lambda $ is the parameter for the line.
- I am looking for further discussion from the answer given by user BMS in this [stack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93698/why-if-the-torque-equals-zero-measured-from-one-point-in-space-it-equals-zero-me)

---

References:

[Equation of a line in space](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/eqnsoflines.aspx)

Comment: Can you grasp the the idea of torque causing rotation of a wheel about its axle? The axle is the line. Looking at the wheel face on, the axle is a point. The torque is the same about the line as it is about the point.

Comment: Right yeah I agree that torque is same along the whole line but we get different values of the torque vector if we actually do evaluate it on different along the line points. However the part along the line is same. So, I'm asking what this extra torque we get from taking different points on the line

Comment: I don't understand you.  What "part" along the line is the same. What do you mean by "extra torque"? You need to be clear. Explain it quantitatively.

Comment: I have edited the question describing the situation using mathematical equations

Comment: Why are you showing your "line in space" as the sum of two vectors? What is the coordinate system for this "line in space"? What is lambda? a constant? In your second to last equation you seem to show it as variable that Tau is a function of. You show $a_o$ as a vector quantity in the equation then you refer to it as a "point". Which is it. What is $v$ in the equation.

Comment: You indicate you have a  force $j$ from "the origin". Origin of what coordinate system? Where is the origin of $j$ with respect to the coordinate system for $r$? You say "we can write torque around $a_o$". Is this the point $a_o$ or the vector $a_o$? Don't bother answering these questions. I don't have the time to untangle this with you.

Comment: I am very sorry, I should have explained my notation better. This was common notation which we had used in my highschool vector algebra class, so I thought it'd be used outside as well. I have taken every point you have said and made a note of it. I'd be happy if you would be kind enough to see the rectifications which I have made. If not, then that's okay too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Another Answer

I realized I did not answer the question directly. The question of if I know the torque from forces on a system summed up at a point, does this torque represent also the torque about a line passing through the point.

The quick answer is not unless the line is parallel to the net force applied to the system. The proof is in the torque transformation equation from one point to another $$ \vec{\tau}_B = \vec{\tau}_A + \vec{F} \times  \vec{r}_{AB}  $$

The two torques are equal only if $\vec{F} \times  \vec{r}_{AB} = \vec{0}$, or the displacement vector is parallel to the net force.

In addition, the term *torque about a line* is a bit ambiguous. Does this line represent a kinematic constraint (as rotation about the line) and the torque is the scalar magnitude applied along the line to balance the applied forces? If that is so, there will be other torque components required that are going to be perpendicular to the line which are going to be ignored.

In this case, the component of torque due to a distance force $\vec{F}$ along a line with direction $\hat{z}$ is given by the triple product

$$ \tau_z = \hat{z} \cdot ( \vec{r} \times \vec{F} ) = \vec{F} \cdot ( \hat{z} \times \vec{r} ) = \vec{r} \cdot ( \vec{F} \times \hat{z})  $$

and the above value is the same anywhere along the line. To prove this, consider a different displacement vector with a parallel offset $\vec{r} + \hat{z} d$,

$$ \tau_z = \vec{F} \cdot ( \hat{z} \times  (\vec{r} + \hat{z} d)) = \vec{F} \cdot ( \hat{z} \times \vec{r} ) \; \checkmark$$

---

### Original Answer

In some sense torque that is due to a force summed at a point is only an indication of where the line of action of the force is located in space. This line of action is the locus of points where there is no torque (or moment of force), or the torque is only parallel to the line. The direction of the line is described by the direction of the force.

Example:

> A force of $$\vec{F} = \pmatrix{ 6 \\ -1 \\ 2}$$
> has equipollent moment about the origin of $$\vec{\tau} = \pmatrix{7 \\ 16 \\ -13}$$
> find the line where the force is applied though.

The location of the line of action is found by

$$ \vec{r} = \tfrac{1}{\| \vec{F} \|^2}  (\vec{F} \times \vec{\tau}) $$

$$ \vec{r} = \tfrac{1}{41} \pmatrix{6 \\ -1 \\2 } \times \pmatrix{7 \\ 16 \\ -13} = 
 \tfrac{1}{41} \pmatrix{ -19 \\ 92 \\ 103 } $$

Let us prove this by calculating $\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$

$$ \vec{\tau} \equiv \tfrac{1}{41} \pmatrix{ -19 \\ 92 \\ 103 } \times \pmatrix{6 \\ -1 \\2} = \pmatrix{7 \\ 16 \\-13} \;\; \checkmark$$

In fact, this is the only useful (geometrical) information one can extract from the torque vector. Well, the location of the line of action, and the amount of parallel torque along the line of action.

The parallel torque is calculated by $$ \vec{\tau}_\parallel = \left( \frac{ \vec{F} \cdot \vec{\tau} }{ \| \vec{F} \|^2 } \right) \vec{F}$$ with the part inside the parenthesis called the pitch (it is a scalar value).

In the above example, the pitch was zero since $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{\tau} =0$, but for a general case of 3D torque, it might be 0, positive, negative, or infinite. It is infinite if there is a pure torque with no net force applied.

- Read related answer(s) also: [Line of action force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98633/line-of-action-force/98640#98640)
- And about the nature of torque: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/329512/392

Comment: Ok, I went on a spree reading your many answers but at the end of it I'm quite confused. These things were never mentioned in any book on classical physics I read and seems like it orginates mostly from robotics. The point which bugs me is that why is there so much mathematics involved in trying to describe a simple physical phenomena... or is it not actually that simple

Comment: What is "equipollent moment "?

Comment: @Buraian - Equipollent moment is the torque that is a result of a force at a distance. When you transfer a load system from one point to another, you have to add the equipollent torque in order not to change the problem. 

> **EQUIPOLLENT** Of two systems of forces, having the same vector sum and the same total torque about an arbitrary point

Comment: Also read [this almost identical answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/329512/392) to a different but related question.

Comment: @Buraian Ok, I added to my answer to more directly answer your question (As I understand it myself).

Comment: Very good answers on rotation answers as always. I have accepted the answer but after going through your answers, I came to understand that the plucker coordinates/ screw theory is an easier way to do rotations but I can't understand what exactly is the plucker coordinates. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: @Buraian - Plucker coordinates of a line is as follows: Instead of using a point and a direction vector to describe a line in space, use the "moment" of the line and the direction. The pair of vectors $(\vec{r} \times \hat{z}, \, \hat{z})$ completely describes the line in space. Additionally, these coordinates have almost a 1:1 correspondence with the net torque of a force. The vector pair $(\vec{r} \times \vec{F}, \, \vec{F})$ are the Plucker coordinates of the line of action of the force.

Comment: Screw theory is an easier way to compose complex mechanical equations of motion in 3D, It takes care of a lot of transformation of coordinates that would have to be handled manually before. But it does not directly address the issues of rotations and how to represent it. Having said that doing the kinematics of 3D joints such as pins and sliders is much easier with screw theory.

Comment: If I understood, the moment is a concept of rotations and torques. How can they be generalized to be used a representation of lines?

Comment: I would just like to say a thank you for the extensive explanations that you have done on these screw theory topics throughout the years. It was a great pleasure going over them and I in fact got interested in the topic so much that I went through all the lectures that you had provided. They were difficult at points for me but I still enjoyed it.

Comment: @Buraian - you can look at [my thesis presentation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344575719_AlexiouThesisPresentationpdf) from 1999.

Comment: Have you done a verbal lecture over that presentation?

Comment: Sorry, those were pre-YouTube days.

Comment: @Buraian - or scan through [my full thesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/27535056_Projective_articulated_dynamics).

Comment: This was a big help, thank you very much

Comment: I fully encourage you to explore these subjects on your own terms. There is still research to be done as there are many questions to be answered. My motivation has been trying to understand how _X_ affects _Y_ in dynamics. Over the years (after my degree) I have learned so much more, partly thanks to the great questions asked here in [Physics.SE]. [For example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/280023/392) on the physical meaning of MMOI.

Answer (score 0):

> However say you wanted to compute the quantity 'torque about the
> line', then you'd find that this quantity is independent of which
> point you take.

In a general situation it is not true. Suppose several particles accelerating in the same direction, as a group of racing cars after the start.

If we trace a line perpendicular to the lane, the torque increases as the point is far away from it.